# Syntax error on Gleam pattern matching using safeguards

Tags: gleam

I've started learning Gleam and am trying to implement a simple filter function to learn more about the language and its syntax. I saw that you can use `case` statements with safeguards, but when I tried on my code, I ran into a syntax error that I could not find how to solve. Do you have any tips on how I can fix this mistake?

This is the code:

```
pub fn filter(list: List(a), function: fn(a) -> Bool) -> List(a) {
  case list {
    [] -> []
    [h, ..t] if function(h) -> [h, ..filter(t, function)]
    [h, ..t] if !function(h) -> filter(t, function)
  }
}
```

And this is the error message from the compiler:

```
error: Syntax error
   ┌─ src/list_ops.gleam:12:25
   │
12 │     [h, ..t] if function(h) -> [h, ..filter(t, function)]
   │                         ^ I was not expecting this
Expected one of: 
"->"
Hint: Did you mean to wrap a multi line clause in curly braces?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [*Guards* section of the The Gleam Language Tour](https://tour.gleam.run/flow-control/guards/):

> Only a limited set of operators can be used in guards, and **functions cannot be called at all**.

This restriction of not calling functions in guards is to avoid side effects in pattern matching since any function may be impure, e.g., it can perform an I/O operation.

You can just pattern-match again on the result of `function(h)`:

```
pub fn filter(list: List(a), function: fn(a) -> Bool) -> List(a) {
  case list {
    [] -> []
    [h, ..t] -> case function(h) {
      True -> [h, ..filter(t, function)]
      False -> filter(t, function)
     }
  }
}
```